# Emacs, How to change some colors in M-x shell?

Tags: emacs, color-scheme

I use Emacs 24 and want to change a color of dirs and files while I'm in shell-mode (`ls` command).  Ideally - depending on rights of the file.

How can i do this?

I tried playing with

```
(setq ansi-color-names-vector
      ["black" "red" "green" "yellow" "PaleBlue" "magenta" "cyan" "white"])
(add-hook 'shell-mode-hook 'ansi-color-for-comint-mode-on)
```

But I think it doesn't work for me.
I have solarized color scheme now. But I do not want to change it's colors, only for shell-mode.

**Edit:**
When I change colors for my system terminal (using .dircolrs file in my home directory) - emacs reads it, BUT *it(emacs) slightly changes colors - it makes a color a bit darker or lighter in shell-mode.*

And I don't know why Emacs does it.

Different dirs colors (games, Public...:
This is system terminal:
[image]
And this is Emacs: [image]

These are changed colors, with default colors and solarized-theme Emacs made blue dirs on a blue background.

I understand that it's not a big problem to find a hack, just want to know why Emacs changes colors a bit.

Comment: My emacs shell uses the font colors set by `zsh` with the emacs buffer background color.  Is this not what your seeing?

Comment: @AndrewMyers, I think yes, then I need to change colors in bash config. Actually I wanted to know if it can be done in emacs.

Comment: I see, if you do `M-x customize-group` `ansi-colors` do you get a customizable group?  I see the ansi-color-names-vector there.

Comment: @AndrewMyers, yes just checked them, but emacs ignores them, still in shell-mode there are different colors, see edit..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is what I use to set Solarized colors for emacs.  I went ahead and posted my whole ansi-term config in case any other settings might be useful.

```
(use-package ansi-term
  :defer t
  :init
  (progn

    ;; ;; Use variable width font faces in current buffer
    (defun my-buffer-face-mode-variable ()
    ;;   "Set font to a variable width (proportional) fonts in current buffer"
      (interactive)
      (setq buffer-face-mode-face '(:family "Menlo For Powerline" :height 100))
      (text-scale-adjust 1)
       (buffer-face-mode))

    (setq system-uses-terminfo nil)
    (add-hook 'term-mode-hook
              '(lambda ()
                 (linum-mode 0)
                 (term-set-escape-char ?\C-z)
                 (term-set-escape-char ?\C-x)
                 (define-key term-raw-map "\C-c" 'term-interrupt-subjob)
                 (define-key term-raw-map (kbd "M-x") 'execute-extended-command)
                 (setq autopair-dont-activate t)
                 (setq ac-auto-start nil)
                 (visual-line-mode -1)
                 ;; (my-buffer-face-mode-variable)
                 ))

    (defun my-term-paste (&optional string)
      (interactive)
      (process-send-string
       (get-buffer-process (current-buffer))
       (if string string (current-kill 0))))

    (defun my-term-pasteboard-paste ()
      (interactive)
      (process-send-string
       (get-buffer-process (current-buffer))
       (ns-get-pasteboard)))

    (add-hook 'term-exec-hook '(lambda ()
                                 (set-buffer-process-coding-system 'utf-8-unix 'utf-8-unix)
                                 (goto-address-mode)
                                 (define-key term-raw-map (kbd "C-y") 'my-term-paste)
                                 (define-key term-raw-map (kbd "s-v") 'my-term-pasteboard-paste)
                                 (let ((base03 "#002b36")
                                       (base02 "#073642")
                                       (base01 "#586e75")
                                       (base00 "#657b83")
                                       (base0 "#839496")
                                       (base1 "#93a1a1")
                                       (base2 "#eee8d5")
                                       (base3 "#fdf6e3")
                                       (yellow "#b58900")
                                       (orange "#cb4b16")
                                       (red "#dc322f")
                                       (magenta "#d33682")
                                       (violet "#6c71c4")
                                       (blue "#268bd2")
                                       (cyan "#2aa198")
                                       (green "#859900"))
                                   (setq ansi-term-color-vector
                                         (vconcat `(unspecified ,base02 ,red ,green ,yellow ,blue
                                                                ,magenta ,cyan ,base2))))))
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, it would be very helpful for me, but I just found what solved the problem (at least I can manually set colors now)

Answer (score 8):

`M-x customize-variable RET ansi-color-names-vector RET`

Existing text will not have been affected, but newly printed text (even in the same shell buffer) will show the new colors.

Comment: I think this is the best answer. After customizing the variable and saving it you can inspect your .emacs file to see how the customization was performed and saved.

Answer (score 7):

Somewhere I found this, and it helped me (I'm a complete newbie, but I thought that`setq ansi-color-names-vector` would be enough):

```
(setq ansi-color-names-vector
      ["black" "tomato" "PaleGreen2" "gold1"
       "DeepSkyBlue1" "MediumOrchid1" "cyan" "white"])
(setq ansi-color-map (ansi-color-make-color-map))  ;; helped line
```

Now `ansi-color-names-vector` works in shell.

Comment: do you know by any chance if there is a way to interactively test those color mappings? I.e. instead of having to restart shell after every change

Comment: @dolzenko, Don't know how to do that