# How to change colors in bash in ansi-term in Emacs

Tags: bash, emacs, elisp

I've try answer from this question [Emacs, How to change some colors in M-x shell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13763912/emacs-how-to-change-some-colors-in-m-x-shell) but got error (when I call ansi-term)

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (error "Invalid face" unspecified)
  internal-get-lisp-face-attribute(unspecified :foreground nil)
  face-attribute(unspecified :foreground nil default)
  face-foreground(unspecified nil default)
  term-handle-colors-array(1)
  term-handle-ansi-escape(#<process *ansi-term*> 109)
  term-emulate-terminal(#<process *ansi-term*> "
\n[01;32mkuba@jcubic[00m:[01;34m~[00m$ ")
  read-event(nil nil 2)
  sit-for(2)
  execute-extended-command(nil "bash")
  call-interactively(execute-extended-command nil nil)
```

(I have `bash` function that call `ansi-term` with /bin/bash).

And author answer don't change anything.

```el
(defun foo ()
  (interactive)
  (setq ansi-color-names-vector
        ["black" "tomato" "PaleGreen2" "gold1"
                 "DeepSkyBlue1" "MediumOrchid1" "cyan" "white"])
  (setq ansi-color-map (ansi-color-make-color-map)))

(add-hook 'term-exec-hook 'foo)
```

This don't change anything:

```el
(setf (aref ansi-color-map 34) '(foreground-color . "red"))
```

what I want it so to change directory color blue color to something lighter (the solution can show how to change all colors as well so it will help other people that will find this question)

here is how it look in xterm:
[image]

and here how it look in Emacs (it's hard to read the directory)
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it:

```el
(set-face-attribute 'term-color-blue nil :foreground "red")
```

now I need to find the name if lighter blue.

**UPDATE**: just found that I can just use hex from xterm:

```el
(set-face-attribute 'term-color-blue nil :foreground "#5555FF")
(set-face-attribute 'term-color-green nil :foreground "#55FF55")
(set-face-attribute 'term-color-red nil :foreground "#FF5555")
(set-face-attribute 'term-color-magenta nil :foreground "#FF55FF")
(set-face-attribute 'term-color-cyan nil :foreground "#FF55FF")
(set-face-attribute 'term-color-yellow nil :foreground "#FFFF55")
```

Comment: Use `list-colors-display` to select the right colour.

Comment: @choroba yes, I found it in Emacs manual.

Comment: @AsifHaswarey if you want to add a different answer please add another answer not edit my own.