# How to customize colors in realgud?

Tags: python, emacs, emacs-faces

I've just installed `realgud` so that I can use `trepan2` for debugging python in emacs. I immediately ran into a serious problem: some of the colors in the `comint` buffer are so light as to be almost invisible: light blue or even yellow on white. How do I change them?

I tried turning off `fontlock-mode` in the buffer, but the colors remain. I have also tried M-x `customize-faces`, but it is not obvious to me which of the hundreds of faces listed is being used by `realgud`. (There are six whose names actually begin with "Realgud", but none of them seems to be relevant.) I scrolled through the entire list, and I couldn't find any yellow or light blue ones. I also tried changing the theme to something with a darker background: that makes yellow visible, but then the dark colors vanish.

EDIT: Following lawlist's suggestion, here are the results of `C-u C-x =`. If I understand this right, it means yellow is hard-coded.

```
             position: 8445 of 9070 (93%), column: 39
            character: 0 (displayed as 0) (codepoint 48, #o60, #x30)
    preferred charset: ascii (ASCII (ISO646 IRV))
code point in charset: 0x30
               syntax: w    which means: word
             category: .:Base, a:ASCII, l:Latin, r:Roman
             to input: type "C-x 8 RET HEX-CODEPOINT" or "C-x 8 RET NAME"
          buffer code: #x30
            file code: #x30 (encoded by coding system utf-8-unix)
              display: by this font (glyph code)
    x:-misc-fixed-medium-r-semicondensed--13-120-75-75-c-60-iso8859-1 (#x30)

Character code properties: customize what to show
  name: DIGIT ZERO
  general-category: Nd (Number, Decimal Digit)
  decomposition: (48) ('0')

There is an overlay here:
 From 8437 to 8450
  face                 (foreground-color . "yellow")
  modification-hooks   (ansi-color-freeze-overlay)


There are text properties here:
  field                output
  fontified            t
  front-sticky         (field inhibit-line-move-field-capture)
  inhibit-line-move-field-capture t
  rear-nonsticky       t

[back]
```

To be honest, I've lost interest in `realgud` anyway. Although the idea of an enhanced `pdb` sounds good, `trepan2` and `realgud` seem to have multiple painful flaws that make them almost unusable.

Thanks.

Comment: Place your cursor on whatever point has the color of particular interest and type `C-u C-x =` and that will tell you what face(s) is/are present at that location.  Then you can `M-x customize-face`.

Comment: Perhaps adjusting the setting for `ansi-color-names-vector` would be helpful?  http://stackoverflow.com/a/13769063/2112489  To see the current setting you can type:  `M-x describe-variable RET ansi-color-names-vector RET`

Comment: Perhaps, but changing the meaning of ANSI colors, which may be used elsewhere in `emacs`, seems like as drastic step. If `realgud` were working well I might consider it, but there are other problems.

Comment: I could be wrong, but I don't believe that `realgud` is responsible for the color settings -- a quick grep revealed that `realgud` uses `ansi-color-filter-apply` which probably would leave a bread crumb trail leading back to `ansi-color-names-vector`.  However, I only spent a couple of minutes looking at the issue.  The only colors that I saw in my brief glimpse at `realgud` were the faces:  `debugger-running`; `debugger-not-running`; `realgud-overlay-arrow1`; `realgud-overlay-arrow2`; `realgud-overlay-arrow3`; `realgud-line-number`; `realgud-file-name`; `realgud-backtrace-number`.

Comment: @LeonAvery Sorry you've lost interest. When you find a problem in any software you are running, consider opening an issue in the project. For this project, the issue trackers are https://github.com/rocky/emacs-dbgr/issues and https://github.com/rocky/python2-trepan/issues . Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Color mappings come from `ansi-term`.

Here is what I have in my .emacs, but note I use a light (white) background. Note that although the main setting is `ansi-term-color-vector`, the color definitions for that have to come beforehand.

```lisp
(defface term-color-darkgreen
  '((t :foreground "DarkGreen" :background "DarkGreen"))
  "Face used to render dark green color code."
  :group 'term)


(defface term-color-cadetblue
  '((t :foreground "CadetBlue" :background "CadetBAlue"))
  "Face used to render dark cadet blue color code."
  :group 'term)

(defface term-color-purple
  '((t :foreground "Purple" :background "Purple"))
  "Face used to render dark Purple color code."
  :group 'term)

(defface term-color-darkgoldenrod
  '((t :foreground "Darkgoldenrod" :background "Darkgoldenrod"))
  "Face used to render dark Darkgoldenrod color code."
  :group 'term)

(defface term-color-ivory4
  '((t :foreground "Ivory4" :background "Ivory4"))
  "Face used to render dark Ivory4 color code."
  :group 'term)


(setq ansi-term-color-vector
      [term
       term-color-black
       term-color-red
       term-color-darkgreen
       term-color-cadetblue
       term-color-blue
       term-color-purple
       term-color-darkgoldenrod
       term-color-ivory4])
```

Comment: I have added the above to the wiki for that project. See https://github.com/rocky/emacs-dbgr/wiki/Customizing-Colors .